# gridle corrupted error in android studio during build

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 116333 found in cache 'C:\Users\zulqa.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.